# About non-separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, geometric-functional-analysis

On Reed & Simon, vol 2, chapter X, problem 4, it is asked:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subspaces of a separable Hilbert space. If $\dim M > \dim N$, prove that $M\cap N^{\perp} \ne \{0\}$.

Here, $\dim V$ is the cardinality of a Hilbert basis for $V$.

The solution is pretty straightforward, since we must have $\dim N = n \in \mathbb{N}$ and therefore it becomes a linear algebra problem.

**My question is:** does it hold for non-separable Hilbert spaces?

I couldn't prove it or think in counterexamples for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the answer is yes.  My sketchy idea is as follows: Consider the orthogonal projection $P(N)$ of $N$ onto $M$ and choose an orthonormal Hilbert basis for this space.  Then extend the basis of $P(N)$ to an orthonormal basis for $M$.  Since $\dim(P(N))<\dim(M)$, the extension is non-trivial.  Any of the new basis vectors in the extension  will be in $N^\perp$. 

I'd need to check with a functional analysis textbook to make sure all the operations described above are legal...

Comment: @Yly. Quite right, And nicely done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More generally, suppose $M$ and $N$ are Hilbert spaces with $\dim M>\dim N$ and let $T:M\to N$ be a bounded linear map.  Then the image of the adjoint map $T^*:N\to M$ cannot be dense in $M$ (the closure of the image is the closed span of the image of an orthonormal basis for $N$, and so has dimension at most $\dim N$).  So there exists nonzero $v\in M$ which is orthogonal to the image of $T^*$.  This means $0=\langle v,T^*w\rangle=\langle Tv,w\rangle$ for all $w\in N$, so $Tv=0$.  That is, the kernel of $T$ is nontrivial.

In your setup, we now immediately conclude that $M\cap N^\perp$ is nontrivial by letting $T:M\to N$ be the orthogonal projection to $N$.